# How find $\min_{a\in\mathbb R}f\left(a \right)$ for $f(a )=\max_{1\le k\le n}\left|x_k+ay_k\right|$?

Tags: geometry, functions

Let them be given points in the plane $P\left(x_k,y_k\right)$, where $k\in \{1,...,n\}$.

Let $f(a )=\max_{1\le k\le n}\left|x_k+ay_k\right|$ , where $a\in\mathbb R$ . How find $\min_{a\in\mathbb R}f\left(a \right)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The term within the absolute value is linear in $a$. So if you have a given parameter $a$, then there are some points for which increasing $a$ will reduce the error, and others for which decreasing $a$ would be an improvement. In an optimal solution, both of these have to be balanced, so you are looking for a situation where two points exhibit the same absolute value error.

So one very naive approach would be the following: take every pair of points $1\le k<m\le n$ and compute the value of $a$ once for $x_k+ay_k=x_m+ay_m$ and a second time for $x_k+ay_k=-(x_m+ay_m)$. Compute $f(a)$ for all these candidate values of $a$, and pick the best. If you want to invest more time thinking about this, you can probably come up with some guidelines about which pairs to consider and which not, but I'd only go that direction if you have enough points that considering all pairs becomes impractical.